# ember transform not being used

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

In my app I'm trying to add a custom transformation for geo coordinates (my API is sending them as a string like "(latitude,longitude)" and I want them to be an object:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Transform.extend({
    deserialize(serialized) {
        let deserialized = serialized.slice(1, -1);

        deserialized = deserialized.split(',');
        console.log('deserialize method');
        return {
            latitude: deserialized[0],
            longitude: deserialized[1]
        };
    },

    serialize(deserialized) {
        console.log('serialize method');
        return '(' + deserialized.latitude + ',' + deserialized.longitude + ')';
    }
});
```

I'm using ember-cli 2.7.0 and the code below is in the file app/transforms/coordinates.js

then in my model I'm using

```
geo: DS.attr('coordinates'),
```

but this doesn't work; the transform is not called at all (I can't see the logs) and the geo field is received as a string as it is sent from the API;

can someone help me to find out the problem here?

Comment: console.log(deserialize method) - change this to console.log('deserialize method') - is it typo error ?

Comment: yes sorry just a typo

Comment: Your code looks perfect. you need provide more debugging step what you tried. otherwise it's very difficult to sort out the issue.

Comment: ok any suggestion about what should I look for, or about where things can be wrong?

Comment: maybe a naming convention. your file name correct? does it show the console.logs ?

Comment: yes... I've double checked... I was wondering, maybe custom serializer for the model interfere in some way with the transform?

Comment: i would rename it to latlong anyway.

Comment: I see that everywhere in the app transforms are not used, and no error is thrown if I use in the model a non-existent attribute like geo: DS.attr('basldfkjas')

Comment: does it log the console.log('deserialize method'); and console.log('serialize method');?